# Is $L^p\cap L^q$ a real intersection?

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

For $p\neq q$, is the notation $L^p\cap L^q$ a set-theoretic intersection, or an intersection taken with respect to some topological embeding ? Since $L^p$'s elements are equivalence classes, I am not sure that such [classes of] functions live in the same "space" (strictly speaking).

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: Of course, we need to embed them if we want to talk about intersection. But the embedding is canonical: both $L^p$ and $L^q$ are subspaces of the space of measurable functions. As for the equivalence class issue, the equivalence relation is the same for $L^p$ and $L^q$ after embedding into the space of measurable functions: two functions are equivalent if and only if they differ on a negligible set.

Comment: Okay so after showing (when it's possible) that the map $f_{L^p} \mapsto f_{L^q}$ is continuous and injective we can see $L^p$ as a subset of $L^q$ for example ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand. What is the definition of your map $f_{L^p} \mapsto f_{L^q}$ exactly?

Comment: $L^p$ and $L^q$ are both subsets of the set of equivalence classes $[f]$ of measurable functions under the equivalence relation $f \sim g$ if and only if $f=g$ a.e. This means you can view $L^p \cap L^q$ as a set-theoretic intersection, it just doesn't naturally inherit a norm structure when you do this.